# How to find the end point for vectors like u = 2i - j?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I'm asked to find the end point of vector u = 2i - j which starts at point (1,-3). I know how to do this for vectors in normal notation like say u = <5,2>. Would I just need to do it in the same way?

Comment: what is a endpoint of a vector?

Comment: Hint: $u=2i-j=\langle 2,-1\rangle$.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius Thank you, that's what I needed to clarify